# jquery doesn't apply css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm getting crazy about a small function that I'm writing.

This function need to set the height of a container equal to the highest UL (3 UL in total and with absolute position) present inside it and, if the second or third UL are lower than the first one, set the height of these UL equal to the first one.

This is the function:

```
function fixNavHeight() {
    var cont = white,
        arr = [];
        lis = $('nav li');

    lis.each(function() {
        var li = $(this);
        li.mouseenter(function() {
            var childrenHeight = $(this).find(secondaryNavigation).height();
            cont.css('height', childrenHeight);
            setHeight(childrenHeight);
        });
    });

    function setHeight(base) {
        arr = [];
        cont.find('ul').each(function() {
            if($(this).is(':visible')) {
                var h = $(this).height();
                console.log(h);
                if(h <= base) {
                    $(this).css('height', base);
                }
                arr.push(h);
                var biggest = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
                cont.css('height', biggest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but if the UL is lower than `base` it doesn't set the css height and I can not understand why.

Can you help me to find the issue?

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: could you try `console.log(base)` after `console.log(h)`?

Comment: I tried another time now and it return "null"...

Comment: Where is `white` coming from in `var cont = white,` ?

Comment: is always cont, I just change the name of the var that I setted outside as a global var.

Comment: Give some more code that is html at least

Comment: Shouldn't the semicolon after `arr = [];` be a comma?

Answer (score 0):

When applying height or width with `.css()` add the **px** suffix, like this:

```
cont.css('height', biggest +'px');
```

Do the same to all your similar calls.

Alternatively if you want to use your current syntax with just the number, then pass the css properties as an object to `.css()`, like this:

```
cont.css({'height': biggest});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `console.log` these items inside the `mouseenter` callback:

```
secondaryNavigation
$(this).find(secondaryNavigation)
$(this).find(secondaryNavigation).height()
```

Check that `secondaryNavigation` is defined. It comes from nowhere in the code (probably some lines above) and it must be accessoible.

Comment: is defined in my global vars. all the variables are well defined.

Comment: It may be better if you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the html structure and so